# How to write this .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, routes

I am setting up a MVC style routing system using mod rewrite within an .htaccess file (and some php parsing too.)

I need to be able to direct different URLs to different php files that will be used as controllers. (index.php, admin.php, etc...)

I have found and edited a rewrite rule that does this well by looking at the first word after the first slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/stats(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /hello.php/$1 [L]
```

However, my problem is I want it to rewrite based on the 2nd word, not the first. I want the first word to be a username. So I want this:

http://www.samplesite.com/username/admin   to redirect to admin.php

instead of:

http://www.samplesite.com/admin

I think I just need to edit the rewrite rule slightly with a 'anything can be here' type variable, but I'm unsure how to do that.

Comment: I don't quite get it, but as far as I understood all you need is to replace `stats` by `admin`, like this:  `admin.*` and replace `hello` with `index`. Not sure if that's what you want, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can prefix [^/]+/ to match and ignore that username/

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+/stats(.*)
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*)$ /hello.php/$1 [L]
```

then http://www.samplesite.com/username/statsadmin  will be redirecte to http://www.samplesite.com/hello.php/statsadmin (or so, I do not know the .htaccess file)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, "an anything can be here type variable" would be something like a full-stop `.` - it means *"any character"*. Also the asterisk `*` means *"zero or more of the preceding character or parenthesized grouped characters"*.

But I don't think you need that...If your matching url will always end in `"admin"` then you can use the dollar sign `$` to match the end of the string.

```
Rewrit­eRule admin$ admin.php [R,NC,L]
```

Rewrites `www.anything.at/all/that/ends/in/admin` to `www.anything.at/admin.php`